# Gitlab-runner deletes files on remote, despite .gitignore

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I tried to find a solution for this problem but couldn't find any.

The issue:

We have image files in `/public/img/InfoNews/example.png` and every time we push an update gitlab-runner removes those files on the remote.

We have `/public/img/InfoNews` in our `.gitignore` this prevents git from uploading local files but not from deleting remote files in that folder for some reason.

I tried to add this path to the cache and artifacts in `.gitlab-ci.yml` without success

A push in the right direction is appreciated.

Our `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
cache:
  paths:
    - vendor/
    - public/img/

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - php artisan cache:clear
    - rm -rf vendor/
    - composer install
    - echo "$env" > "$(pwd)/.env"
    - php artisan migrate

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - .env
      - public/img/
```

EDIT:

I also tried

```
cache:
  untracked: true
  paths:
    - vendor/
    - public/img/
```

But it still deletes the files.

Comment: Can you paste the relevant bits in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` please?

Comment: @Rekovni posted content of your file

Comment: it removing the file from your local?

Comment: @bahram I don't have the file locally, they are images that are uploaded on the remote machine. I assume gitlab-runner does a hard reset every time and removes everything that's not in the repo and I can't stop it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed it myself.

Gitlab-runner runs `git clean` after checkout and ignores `.gitignore`files per default for whatever reason.

To prevent files from being deleted you have to add this to your gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
variables:
  GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS: -x -f -e public/**
```

-x ignores .gitignore files -f forces the clean and -e excludes files from the clean, the ** means every file and folder